# How to extract sentence in between two words and exclude special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following sentence from a json string and i want to parse only the words for the "value" part of the string i.e **Service Copy**

```
"customtext_230216":"self":"https://jsonapi.com/restsv/api/13/customtext/11233","value":"Service Copy","id":"11211"}
```

After several searches on SO i was able to get the regex expression

```
\b(?<=value)(.*?)(?=\s*id)
```

and the result is

```
":"Service Copy","
```

How can I enhance this so that the special characters are not captured
expected result :

```
Service Copy
```

Comment: Why are you not using `JSON.parse()` method to pars JSON string?

Comment: That is not a valid JSON String.

Comment: there are several nesting for the complete JSON, so since this line is unique in the context wouldn't regex be easier ?

Comment: @Vishnudev, you are write, its not valid JSON as its just part of the complete JSON, since i am only interested in this part, wouldn't regex be easier ?

Comment: You should never be extracting values from JSON as a string using regex even if it is heavily nested. The structure is in place for a specific reason of hierarchical organization of data. You will face difficulties extracting multiple data type formats like array using regex. Hence not advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to stick with regex:

```
(?<=value\":\")(.*?)(?=\s*\",\"id)
```

Basically took out the word boundary in the beginning and defined the special characters (quotes, colons, etc) outside of the capturing group.

However, there are better ways to extract values from JSON and I encourage you to look at those as this could potentially be a brittle solution.

Comment: come to think of it i agree with you this would be a brittle solution, i appreciate your quick response.